# Qt4: как установить и получить код ошибки для процесса при завершении QApplication

Tags: qt, qt4

Если я из приложения `QApplication` номер 1 запускаю другое приложение `QApplication` номер 2 как `QProcess`, и при завершении приложения номер 2 мне необходимо получить `ProcessError` и другие данные о процессе, как это лучше сделать?

Для `QProcess` есть `enum`-ы

```
    enum ProcessError {
        FailedToStart, 
        Crashed,
        Timedout,
        ReadError,
        WriteError,
        UnknownError
    };
    enum ProcessState {
        NotRunning,
        Starting,
        Running
    };
    enum ExitStatus {
        NormalExit,
        CrashExit
    };
```

`ProcessState` я получаю без проблем, `ExitStatus` соответствует кодам выхода для `QCoreApplication`, а как получать `ProcessError`? Вернее, как установить?

В приложении номер 2 я лишь устанавливаю статус выхода: `::exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` или `::exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)`, в документации говорится, что если нужно передать код ошибки, то его нужно передавать в виде `::exit(код_ошибки)`, так я могу по идее передать любое число, но хотелось бы использовать стандартный `enum` для `QProcess`, и не перекрывать `exit_code`.

Comment: Ничего не понял. Чем Вам не нравится `int QProcess::exitCode() const`? Ничего перекрывать не надо. Во втором приложении вызываете `exit(код_завершения)`, в первом проверяете.

Comment: @kff попробую объяснить. `exit(код_завершения)` - если я правильно понимаю, это если только свои коды добавлять, и оба приложения должны их знать. Если я буду передавать, например, `exit(QProcess::FailedToStart)` - согласно `enum` `ProcessError` этот код равен `0`, тот же код имеет `EXIT_SUCCESS`. Возникает неоднозначность. И мне нужно, чтобы можно было использовать не `int QProcess::exitCode() const`, а `int QProcess::error() const`

Comment: @kff Или есть какой-то стандартный набор кодов завершения, кроме `EXIT_FAILURE` и `EXIT_SUCCESS`?

Comment: У Вас небольшая путаница в голове. `QProcess::FailedToStart` в `exit` использовать не надо. Более того, самому его вообще нигде не надо устанавливать, его можно только читать. В `exit` передаётся просто число. А набор кодов завершения Вы устанавливаете сами. Стандартных наборов нет. Есть только общепринятое соглашение: *ноль - нет ошибок, не ноль - есть ошибки*.

Comment: @kff вот я об этом и пишу - мне нужно устанавливать не код возврата, а код конкретной ошибки. Есть ошибки/нет ошибок - этого недостаточно.

Comment: Так и я о том же. Общепринято **передавать код ошибки** в `exit`. И общепринято **передавать ноль в случае отсутствия ошибок**. Т.е. *ненулевой код возврата есть код ошибки*.

Comment: Определите в отдельном заголовке свой собственный enum с описанием своих собственных кодов ошибок и используйте этот заголовок в обоих приложениях.